# No space between words while reading and extracting the text from a pdf file in python?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Hello Community Members,

I want to extract all the text from an e-book with .pdf as the file extension. I came to know that python has a package `PyPDF2` to do the necessary action. Somehow, I have tried and able to extract text but it results in inappropriate space between the extracted words, sometimes the results is the result of 2-3 merged words.

Further, I want to extract the text from page 3 onward, as the initial pages deals with the cover page and preface. Also, I don't want to include the last 5 pages as it contains the glossary and index.

Does there exist any other way to read a .pdf binary file with NO ENCRYPTION?

The code snippet, whatever I have tried up to now is as follows.

```
import PyPDF2
def Read():
    pdfFileObj = open('book1.pdf','rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    #discerning the number of pages will allow us to parse through all #the pages
    num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
    count = 0
    global text
    text = []
    while(count < num_pages):
         pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
         count +=1
         text += pageObj.extractText().split()
         print(text)
 Read()
```

Comment: I know some PDF exporting tools will individually place every word, rather than a string with spaces in it -- i.e., say `put "hello," at (0, 0). put "world!" at (100, 0). put "this is a" at (0, 20). put "test") at (600, 20).` The specific pixel values chosen will lead to the equivalent space of one, er, space, but trying to get the words will return the incorrect value. I don't know if that's your issue here, but it'd be worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks. Does PyPDF2 supports this pixel values or I need a separate tool to export the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does pypdf stuff text with extra spaces, while Windows Search does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546531/why-does-pypdf-stuff-text-with-extra-spaces-while-windows-search-does-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
import PyPDF2

def Read(startPage, endPage):
    global text
    text = []
    cleanText = ""
    pdfFileObj = open('myTest2.pdf', 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    while startPage <= endPage:
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(startPage)
        text += pageObj.extractText()
        startPage += 1
    pdfFileObj.close()
    for myWord in text:
        if myWord != '\n':
            cleanText += myWord
    text = cleanText.split()
    print(text)

Read(0,0)
```

Read() parameters --> Read(first page to read, last page to read)

**Note:**  To read the first page starts from 0 not from 1 (as for example in an array).