# Why does pypdf stuff text with extra spaces when extracting text?

Tags: pypdf, python-3.11

`pypdf==3.11.0`, like previous versions, returns text strings with the occasional inserted single space. But Windows Search and the "Find" in Adobe reader find the text unadulterated, and if you try finding the text string with the extra spaces inserted it is not found.

Here for the record is a code sample:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader(path)
for page in reader.pages:
    text = page.extract_text()
    lines = text.splitlines()
```

The PDF page displayed by Acrobat reader contains the following line:

> HERMES INVESTMENT MGMT US SMID Equity L Hgd Acc (GBP)

The text extracted by pypdf `reader` is:

> HERMES INVESTMEN T MGMT US SMID Equ ity L Hgd Acc (GBP)

I understand the difficulty of extracting continuous text from a PDF,
but, and this is my point, searching in Acrobat Reader for "INVESTMENT MGMT" finds the string while searching for "INVESTMEN T MGMT" does not find it.  And, the same result using the Windows Explorer search facility.

If Windows Search can read the string without extra spaces, why can't pypdf?

Comment: Interesting answer.  I wonder what happens if Adobe Reader is not installed on a Windows system?

Comment: The original (interesting) answer from K J has disappeared, I wonder what happened to it?  Was it deleted?

Comment: Investigating further I found pdfplumber which seems to avoid stuffing extra spaces into text strings when extracting text.  Will use going forward.

Comment: Both `pdfplumber` and `pymudpdf` was able to deal with the extra spaces for me.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read [pypdf: Why text extraction from PDFs is hard](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html?#why-text-extraction-is-hard)

### Why whitespaces are hard

For the whitespace problem, think of every single character being absolutely positioned on the document. So `MGMT US` might be represented as:

```
(M, 0, 0)
(G, 10, 0)
(M, 20, 0)
(T, 25, 0) <--- note that it doesn't have to be always the same distance!
(U, 35, 0) <--- note that there is no "space" positioned!
(S, 45, 0)
```

Given something like that, you have to apply heuristics to make a best guess if there should be a whitespace or not. That depends on the font being used. In `pypdf` we have a `space_width` parameter e.g. in [_page.py::PageObject._extract_text](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/blob/main/pypdf/_page.py#L1823).

I simplified the situation, but you get the idea.

[Liguatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)) should be supported directly by the font, so that it's actually a single character. However, some fonts might not do it. Using Kerning is always an option to improve the overall picture the text forms.

[Kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) is what causes the issue.

The next issue is that you might be biased in your observation (**Observer Bias**). It's typically easy to improve the space-situation for one specific PDF. But that improvement might make it worse for many others.

It's important to improve the overall situation. That is why I created https://github.com/py-pdf/benchmarks with several very different PDF documents. So far that is not tailored towards whitespace ... maybe I should create specific tests for that

### What pypdf could do better

pypdf is not perfect. We improved it a lot since April 2022, but there are a few things we could do to improve the whitespace situation (most important first):

1. **Support Tagged PDFs**: See https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/1168
2. **Better heuristics**: I can see that some libraries do a better job in many cases for whitespaces than pypdf does. I would be very interested to hear from them how they do it. Maybe we can adjust pypdf to use similar ideas.
3. **Font support**: This is a never ending story. Adding more fonts with specific rules.
4. **Producer support**: If you know which software produced the PDF you can look for the exact pattern that it would apply. So far, we don't have specific rules depending on the producer. I'm not sure I want that, because there are so many producers ... maybe if
5. **OCR**: That is something pypdf **could** do, but as long as I'm the maintainer we will never do. I'm also pretty certain others are not doing it. It would require too many changes/additions that are not the core issue pypdf wants to solve. OCR is a very different beast. But yes, converting the PDF to an image and then extracting text might sometimes lead to better results.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :-) I have avoided writing about Windows Search as I have no insights into what they are doing. I can only shed light on what pypdf is doing / why it's not always perfect / what we plan to (not) do. I hope the answer is still helpful :-)